# Discord Nickname Command with a specific format

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am relatively new to coding. I already coded a bot with a "nickname changer". My problem is, that I want it to change to a specific format:
*"!nick @JohnDoe John" changes name to "JohnDoe [John]"*

```
module.exports = client => {
    
    const command = require('../command')

    command(client, 'nick', (message) => {

        if (!message.member.permissions.has("CHANGE_NICKNAME")) return message.channel.send("Missing Permissions!");
        if (!message.mentions.users.first()) return message.channel.send("Tag somebody!");   
            const user = message.mentions.members.first();
            user.setNickname(message.content.replace('!nick ', '').replace(user, ''));
    })
}
```

It is for a private server, where everyone can see the users Gametag and their real name.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

PS: If there are better ways for that code pls tell me. As I said, I am a noob in programming stuff

Comment: You could use this format for displaying it:

```lang-js

`${userName} [${nickName}]`

```
(igonore lang-js)
this will make string that reads like this:

username [nickname]

Comment: Do i need "const" for "userName"? I tried this:
`const user = message.mentions.members.first();
 const userName = user.id;
 const nickName = message.content.replace('!nick ', '').replace(user, ''); 
 user.setNickname('${userName} [${nickName}]');`

Comment: you need to use `` instead of '' when you use ${variables}

Comment: I know. I changed because of the text format on this website. It still don't work. It says that the command's too long: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body , nick: Must be 32 or fewer in length.

Comment: i got it check my answer
the problem was that it used user id which is 18 letters long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

command:

 `!test @user tag`

result:

 `@user[tag]`

```
var  Discord = require('discord.js');
var  client = new Discord.Client();
module.exports = {
  name: 'gamertag',
  description: "this is a gamertag command",
  
  execute(message, args){
    if (!message.member.permissions.has("CHANGE_NICKNAME")) return message.channel.send("Missing Permissions!");
        if (!message.mentions.users.first()) return message.channel.send("Tag somebody!");   
        const user = message.mentions.members.first(); //get mentioned user username
        const username = message.mentions.members.first().displayName; //get mentionde user display username(normal username)
        let  nickName = message.content.split(/\s+/).slice(2); //exclude first 2 words 
        var combined = `${username}[${nickName}]`
        user.setNickname(combined);
    }
}
```